# How to format results of a cell within SQL data pull

Tags: sql-server, string-formatting

I was trying to figure out a simple solution to my problem. At present I am using a SQL Server 2012 and was trying to figure out how to pull a column that has multiple pieces of data and not break them up but rather put them on a new line. For example...

The Cell has data that looks like this:

```
"12345, 23456, 34567, 45678"
```

What I am trying to accomplish in SQL is to present the data like this:

```
12345,
23456,
34567,
45678
```

I want the data to remain in the same cell just take this form when i Export it into Excel. I was hoping to have it formatted like this before it goes into excel because I am dropping the data pull directly into a pivot table.

What I have tried is using

```
Cast(v.ID as VARCHAR)+ Char(10)
Cast(v.ID as VARCHAR)+ Char(13)
```

However these aren't just adding a new line in the cell like i'd like its creating new lines in the data

Additionally I am using a STUFF command to pull all these ID's together in the first place.

```
STUFF((Select CAST(v.ID as VARCHAR)+ ', '

From Source

Where CriteriaIsMet
For XML Path('')),1,0,'') as MonitorID
```

The ultimate goal is to have the ID's show in a line vertically rather than horizontally because once in a pivot table if you have 10+ id's they visually fall off the cell.

If any of that made sense I'd be incredibly appreciative of any help. 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT REPLACE('12345, 23456, 34567, 45678', ', ', ',' + CHAR(13)) AS Result`

This works just fine.
Cell looks like that:

```
Result
12345, 23456, 34567, 45678
```

However when you copy-paste your results it outputs what you expected:

```
12345,
23456,
34567,
45678
```

What I did is I just replaced 'comma plus space' into 'comma plus break'.

If I misunderstood you, can you explain better what needs to be done? So I can try and help you :)

Comment: So that is what i'm looking to do, however, I am trying to figure out now how to apply it to my STUFF command.

    STUFF((Select REPLACE(CAST v.ID as VARCHAR) , ', ', ',' + Char(13))  causing the id numbers to merge together no comma's no breaks. trying different variations

Comment: So i'm doing 
as VARCHAR) + ', ' , ', ', +CHAR(13))
and the results are instead of a break it gives me this
6615256&#x0d;6615257&#x0D

Comment: now i'm guessing its doing that because i'm placing the command in the line that is happening while its being created. I'm not sure if i need to place it at the end of the pull where somewhere with the For XML Path piece

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can be achieved using `STUFF` command.

Please have a look at below query which might help you.

```
Select Stuff((Select '
' + K.ID
From Source
Where ScenarioMet
FOR Xml Path(''),TYPE).value('.','VARCHAR(1000)'),1,1,''))
```